# How to handle concurrent access to a Scala collection?

Tags: scala, collections, concurrency

I have an Actor that - in its very essence - maintains a list of objects. It has three basic operations, an add, update and a remove (where sometimes the remove is called from the add method, but that aside), and works with a single collection. Obviously, that backing list is accessed concurrently, with add and remove calls interleaving each other constantly.

My first version used a ListBuffer, but I read somewhere it's not meant for concurrent access. I haven't gotten concurrent access exceptions, but I did note that finding & removing objects from it does not always work, possibly due to concurrency.

I was halfway rewriting it to use a var List, but removing items from Scala's default immutable List is a bit of a pain - and I doubt it's suitable for concurrent access.

So, basic question: What collection type should I use in a concurrent access situation, and how is it used?

(Perhaps secondary: Is an Actor actually a multithreaded entity, or is that just my wrong conception and does it process messages one at a time in a single thread?)

(Tertiary: In Scala, what collection type is best for inserts and random access (delete / update)?)

Edit: To the kind responders: Excuse my late reply, I'm making a nasty habit out of dumping a question on SO or mailing lists, then moving on to the next problem, forgetting the original one for the moment.

Comment: An actor processes one message at a time. Concurrency with actors comes from asynchronous message processing, not from an actor processing multiple messages concurrently.

Comment: What is the business problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @ViktorKlang: I'll try to explain it a bit. A user sends a model object called a NotificationPlan to the server through a REST service. According to the NotificationPlan, a number of Notification objects are generated, which will at one point in the future be sent back to the users (in the form of an Apple push notification).

In this case, the actor with the list as described in the question maintains a list of NotificationPlans in memory, so that the user can update or remove his plan after initially adding it.

Answer (score 12):

Take a look at the scala.collection.mutable.Synchronized* traits/classes.

The idea is that you mixin the Synchronized traits into regular mutable collections to get synchronized versions of them.

For example:

```
import scala.collection.mutable._
val syncSet = new HashSet[Int] with SynchronizedSet[Int]
val syncArray = new ArrayBuffer[Int] with SynchronizedBuffer[Int]
```

Comment: Please don't do this, it doesn't scale.

Comment: As of Scala 2.11, SyncronizedSet's are deprecated: Synchronization via traits is deprecated as it is inherently unreliable. Consider java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap[A,Unit] as an alternative.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to synchronize the state of the actors. The aim of the actors is to avoid tricky, error prone and hard to debug concurrent programming.

Actor model will ensure that the actor will consume messages one by one and that you will never have two thread consuming message for the same Actor.

Answer (score 4):

Scala's immutable collections are suitable for concurrent usage.

As for actors, a couple of things are guaranteed as explained [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/jmm.html) the Akka documentation.

- the actor send rule: where the send of the message to an actor happens before the receive of the same actor.
- the actor subsequent processing rule: where processing of one message happens before processing of the next message by the same actor.

You are not guaranteed that the same thread processes the next message, but you *are* guaranteed that the current message will finish processing before the next one starts, and also that at any given time, only one thread is executing the receive method.

So that takes care of a given Actor's persistent state.  With regard to shared data, the best approach as I understand it is to use immutable data structures and lean on the Actor model as much as possible.  That is, "do not communicate by sharing memory; share memory by communicating."

Answer (score -1):

> What collection type should I use in a concurrent access situation, and how is it used?

See @hbatista's answer.

> Is an Actor actually a multithreaded entity, or is that just my wrong conception and does it process messages one at a time in a single thread

The second (though the thread on which messages are processed may change, so don't store anything in thread-local data). That's how the actor can maintain invariants on its state.